# Url Change on Radio Button Selected and Submited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying get something as described in the subject, when the submit or order now button is clicked, it should go to URL based on the radio button selection. But this below form is appending ?rr=on  which creating issues with my urls.

The form is:

```
<form id="account2">
        <p>
        <input type="radio" id="r20" name="rr" onclick="document.getElementById('account2').action='http://seomagz.com/';"/>
        <label for="r20" class="rating"><span1></span1><span class="one_month">36 mo</span> <span class="one_month2">Rs.530</span><span class="one_month">/mo</span> </label>

        <p>
        <input type="radio" id="r21" name="rr" onclick="document.getElementById('account2').action='http://www.google.com/';"/>
        <label for="r21"><span1></span1><span class="one_month">24 mo</span> <span class="one_month2">Rs.533</span><span class="one_month">/mo</span> </label>

        <p>
         <input type="radio" id="r22" name="rr" onclick="document.getElementById('account2').action='http://www.google.com/';"/>
        <label for="r22"><span1></span1><span class="one_month">12 mo</span> <span class="one_month2">Rs.541</span><span class="one_month">/mo</span> </label>

        <p>
         <input type="radio" id="r23" name="rr" onclick="document.getElementById('account2').action='http://www.googlefg.com/';" />
        <label for="r23"><span1></span1><span class="one_month">3 mo</span> <span class="one_month2">Rs.549</span><span class="one_month">/mo</span> </label>


    </div>
<button type="submit" class="ordernow1" style="margin-top:63px;"><p>Order Now</p></button></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="account2" method="post">
```

You should also be closing your `<p>` tags, makes good practice

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be reproduced here

try using `action='post'`

here's the fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/hAGPr/
```